# Difference between git push -f origin master and git push origin master --force?

Tags: git, github, version-control, push

Today, I  was trying  to permanently delete  a file in all commits  using  `git filter-branch`.   After, I needed to force a push obviously, in order to ensure that all collaborators have  access to the repository without this file.

So, I tried `git push -f origin <branch-name>`, which gave me the usual "make sure you have the correct access rights" error.

So, I did the following commands:

```
git push -f origin <branch-name>
git checkout <branch-name>
git push origin <branch-name>:<branch-name> --force
```

After `git push origin master --force` and it worked.  Why and how is this different?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you make the changes in `branch-name` or `master`?  Your question is not clear about this.

Comment: I made changes to a branch other than master.  I tried to make the question more general by using `branch-name` since  `master` is a branch.  If this changes the answer to the question, then sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `git push -f <remote> <branch>` and `git push --force <remote> <branch>`. `-f` is simply the shorthand for `--force`.

`git checkout <branch-name>` checkouts out `<branch-name>`. Since you're specifying what branch you wanted to push, it didn't have any effect.

`git push origin <branch-name>:<branch-name> --force` pushed your commits in your local `<branch-name>` to the remote's `<branch-name>`. It is the same as `git push origin <branch-name> --force` since the branch names are the same.

If you got an access error with one but not the other, you probably didn't use the right credentials.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: I've updated my question with more detail -- sorry for not including this earlier.